# ListView values are all shown false (in Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have three textview in rowlayout.xml. However when I run my app all the values except rating is shown as false.

rowlayout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"        
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@+id/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rating"    
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@+id/distance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:text="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the MainActivity.java class:

```
package com.SahilSiddesh.far4;    
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
    "Linux", "OS/2" };
    String[] distance = new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    String[] rating = new String[] {"2","2.5", "5", "4.6", "0","1","3","4","5","1"};

    // use your custom layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterValues = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.name, values);
    setListAdapter(adapterValues);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDistance = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.distance, distance);
    setListAdapter(adapterDistance);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterRating = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.rating, rating);
    setListAdapter(adapterRating);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 3 adapters for a list, which is wrong.
A list should match with only 1 adapter.

The reason why only rating has text is because you have

```
   setListAdapter(adapterRating);
```

as the last setListAdapter.

You should build a custom adapter that takes 3 arrays, inflate rowlayout.xml, and set all text manually in your case.
You can also create a new class that has 3 fields, and create an array of that class, and pass that array into a custom adapter instead of 3 arrays.

[Custom adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example)

Answer (score 1):

You implementation is totally wrong, You are setting three different adapter on the list view, so the last one will override the previous one.

And for array use Java POJO class.

```
class Platform{
     String os;
     String distance;
     String rating;
}
```

Then create a list or array of `Platform` class, and pass it to your custom adapter.

You have to use a custom list adapter, please go through [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: Ok thank you. Also please can you tell me how to have images (as in the ic_launcher above) to be set dynamically. I mean I am thinking of implementing images for corresponding rating. Eg: if the rating is 4 out of 5, then I will have an image of 4 stars. I am asking for relevant code or example and not how to create the image (in photoshop).

Comment: You can set the image in your adapter getView method, please go through the link, how to use a custom adapter, then you can use the image as well

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a custom adapter. Using the base adapter is wrong, check this [PDF](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) for more information.